# Why still adding even with validation form?

Tags: vue.js, axios

When I click the button on my modal with an empty field on my input its give me an undefined value on my console. And when I put a value on my input and click the button it is adding to my database. The problem is even the empty field or the undefined value are also adding to my database and the sweetalert is not working. I want to prevent the empty field adding to my database and prevent the undefined. Can somebody help me?

```
            //start of method
     checkForm: function(e) {
          if (this.category_description) {
            return true;
          }

          this.errors = [];

          if (!this.category_description) {
            this.errors.push('Category required.');
          }
          e.preventDefault();
        },

      addCategory : function() {
        axios({
            method : "POST",
            url : this.urlRoot + "category/add_category.php",
            data : {
                description : this.category_description
            }
        }).then(function (response){
            vm.checkForm(); //for FORM validation
            vm.retrieveCategory();
            console.log(response);
            swal("Congrats!", " New category added!", "success");   
            vm.clearData();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response);
        });
    },
     //end of method

     <form id="vue-app" @submit="checkForm">
    <div class="modal" id="myModal" > <!-- start add modal -->
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content " style="height:auto">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title"> Add Category </h4>
                  <button @click="clearData" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_description" name="category_description" v-model="category_description" placeholder="Enter Description">
                            <p v-if="errors.length">
                                <span v-for="error in errors"> {{ error }} </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit"@click="category_description !== undefined ? addCategory : ''" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Category </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to stop this is adding data check. And condition check at top of your method.`category_description !== undefined`. Btw, move your `e.preventDefault()` to top too.

Comment: This is not working the undefined still showing and adding to my database

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking on `Add Category` button, it is triggering the `addCategory` along with your validation method.

The return value of validation method has no impact on triggering of `addCategory`.

This issue can be handled in following ways.

1. Call `addCategory` only when there is some valid data

`<button type="submit" @click="category_description != undefined ? addCategory() : ''" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Category </button>`

2. Call the validation method inside addCategory and then proceed.

Comment: The undefined is not showing in my console. But the problem it's not adding to my database anymore. I update the codes above. I add this to my addCategory 'vm.checkForm()'

Comment: @MayaLi Update the code. `addCategory' should be a function call.

Comment: How do I do that sir?

Answer (score 0):

First of all do this:

```
-  <button type="submit" @click="category_description !== undefined ? addCategory : ''" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Category </button>
+  <button type="submit" @click.prevent="addCategory" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Category </button>
```

and then in addCategory:

```
addCategory() {
  if (!this.category_description) {
    return;
  } else {
  //  do your stuff here
  }

}
```

Comment: not working sir! its not adding to my database. The modal is not closing